# PostgreSQL CHECK Constraint with 'LIKE' fails but succeeds with 'SIMILAR TO' and/or POSIX '!~*'

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, sql-like

I am using PostgreSQL 10.1.

I create the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE country
(
    id        smallint NOT NULL,
    alpha2    character varying(2) NOT NULL,
    alpha3    character varying(3) NOT NULL,
    name      character varying(38) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT country_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT country_alpha2_key UNIQUE (alpha2),
    CONSTRAINT country_alpha3_key UNIQUE (alpha3),
    CONSTRAINT country_name_key UNIQUE (name),
    CONSTRAINT country_alpha2_check
        CHECK ((char_length(alpha2::text)) = 2 AND
               (alpha2 NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z]%')),
    CONSTRAINT country_alpha3_check
        CHECK ((char_length(alpha3::text)) = 3 AND
               (alpha3 NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z]%')),
    CONSTRAINT country_name_check CHECK (char_length(name::text) > 0)
);
```

Unfortunately, the following statement succeeds although it should not:

```
INSERT INTO country (id, alpha2, alpha3, name)
    VALUES (1, '11', '111', 'Haiti');
```

If I substitute `LIKE` with `SIMILAR TO` then the above statement fails as it should.

If I substitute `NOT LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z]%'` with POSIX Regex `!~* '[^a-zA-Z]'` then the above statement does fail, too, as it should.

Is there any explanation why `LIKE` fails? Most of the examples I have seen use `LIKE`! It seems that LIKE doesn't like to work!

Tia

Comment: `LIKE` does not support regular expressions: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE

Comment: OK, but it supports pattern matching (chapter 9.7.1 in manual). '%[^a-zA-Z]%' is a pattern or a regular expression?

Comment: Oooohhh! By adding the '^' character to '%[a-zA-Z]%', it ('%[^a-zA-Z]%') becomes a regular expression from a pattern. Is this the explanation?

Comment: Have you read the documentation that was linked to above? LIKE uses `_` and `%` for patterns, SIMILAR TO uses slightly different patterns, and regexes are something else entirely.

Comment: `LIKE '%[^a-zA-Z]%'` means: any character followed by the character `[` followed by `^` followed by `a`  followed by `-` followed by `z` followed by `A` followed by `-` followed by `Z` followed by `]` followed by any character

Comment: Thanks  `mu is too short`. Now I understand the differences!

Answer (score 1):

The explanation is obvious and is hidden in a mere technicality:

`LIKE` in **PostgreSQL** uses **only two** characters to form a `pattern`: underscore `_` and percent sign `%`.

Comment: This is how LIKE is specified in the SQL standard not something special to Postgrs